# Testing Amazon In-App purchases with Adobe AIR

Tags: air, in-app-purchase, amazon-appstore

The only documentation I can find for testing in-app purchases [is this](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs/adobe-testing), which instructs me to install the deprecated Amazon SDK Tester APK for Amazon's IAP 1.0, which seems like a bad idea.

I have the Amazon IAP ANE in Flash CS 6.

I've tried installing Amazon's newer [App Tester app](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BN3YZM2) and have downloaded and copied `amazon.sdktester.json` with all our in-app items from Amazon to /root/sdcard/ on my Kindle Fire HD 7, but no callback is fired when I call the IAP API with `AmazonPurchase.amazonPurchase.loadItemData( arrayOfIAPSkus );`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 tester apps:

1. Amazon SDK Tester - for testing IAP v1.0
2. [Amazon App Tester](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BN3YZM2) - for testing IAP v2.0

The Adobe AIR ANE is for Amazon IAP v1.0, so you should use Amazon SDK Tester.

> Note: App Tester is not supported for IAP v1.0 and is incompatible
>   with the SDK Tester tool included in the download for IAP v1.0. If
>   your app uses both IAP v1.0 and Mobile Associates APIs, you will need
>   to install/uninstall App Tester and SDK Tester to test your app
>   locally as you work with each API set. If you upgrade to IAP v2.0, you
>   will only need to have App Tester installed on your device.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs-v2/installing-and-configuring-app-tester

Comment: Thank you! I think I figured this out just as you were responding. I don't know how I missed it. First time coding in ActionScript and first time writing In-App Purchases, so it's an adventure.

Comment: Glad you figured it out ;)

Comment: Where can I find the ane for the IAP v2 ? Amazon site says it is included in Google Play game center but I can't find anything like IAP there..and also there is no amazon docs for it at all

Comment: @deyan-vitanov, as far as I know, there's no Adobe AIR ANE for Amazon IAP v2 available at the moment. I'm not sure which Amazon site you're referring to. Can you provide a link?

Comment: Sure @Christina - here is it: https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/IAP+Adobe+Plugin

Comment: @deyan-vitanov, I think you're referring to the "[Adobe Gaming Website](http://gaming.adobe.com/getstarted) link, not "Google Play game center". The "[Adobe Gaming Website](http://gaming.adobe.com/getstarted)" is where you can find the "[Adobe Gaming Tools](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/tools.html)", such as Flash Builder and Flash CC. If you're looking for the ANE for Amazon IAP v1, it is bundled within the [Amazon Mobile App SDK](https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/sdk).